# How to build HTML messages in an MVC3 application for sending?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, email

I was thinking about this during my morning shower, how can I construct HTML messages in an MVC3 application?

I was thinking something like using a `PartialView` and invoking the resulting HTML, saving the it as a string to use it in the HtmlMessage body.

Instead of doing something like:

```
string body = @"<html><h1>This is an email. Yuk formatting and hard to maintain.</h1></html>";
```

I could do something like:

```
string body = Html.Action("WelcomeEmail", "Emails");
```

Since MVC3 is so robust and mature, there must be a standard way of doing this, correct?

What is the recommended approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/) allows you to send emails as rendered Views

Comment: I think I like Postal better than Mvc.Mailer - It seems much cleaner.

Comment: I agree. I had tried Mvc.Mailer per Hanselman's post too and found it to be too much. Postal was a lot simpler to get working

Comment: I also notice that it's made by Andrew Davey, the author of Cassette. Quite a pedigree this guy has going on huh? Sold instantly on that alone. Installing the NuGet now!

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest [Mvc.Mailer](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek2MvcMailerSendsMailsWithASPNETMVCRazorViewsAndScaffolding.aspx).

You get all of the benefit of the MVC framework along with scaffolding support.